# Show checkbox only when a specific form-field is non-empty (Django)

Tags: python, html, css, django, django-forms

I have a model

```py
class my_model(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE,null=True)
    start_price = models.FloatField(default=0)
    last_price = models.FloatField(default=0)
    will_buy= models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

and my form

```py
class my_form(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = my_model
```

In my template I want `will_buy` first being visible when `last_price` is filled in. Best of all will be as a kind "slow unpacking", but first of all I just need it to be hidden when `last_price` is empty.

Comment: I would say that this is something that has to be done on JS side and not on Django.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in Django template directly if last_price == 0 then you can set it hidden else visible.

```
{% if last_price ==0 %}
    <input type=checkbox name=will_by style="visibility:hidden"> will Buy
{% else %}
    
   <input type=checkbox name=will_by style="visibility:visible"> will Buy
{% endif %}
```